# Learning about Honda Civic Underhood parts

Tags: engine, honda, civic, part-identification

[image: inside my car]
 I need help, I’m learning about my car, and I can’t seem to find an answer on what this part is, due to not knowing what it is, and not knowing how to ask google. It’s the part with a crack in it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the exhaust manifold : brown in colour with the vertical crack. The part that is screwed into it with the wires is the oxygen or Lambda sensor for the emissions / engine control.

Comment: if the answer is good enough then you can give it a "tick" as accepted. Bu you're welcome anyway :)

Comment: While Honda parts are typically high quality, you may want to consider a quality aftermarket manifold. Some will have a lifetime warranty. They look at where the OEM part failed and correct the design flaws.

Comment: I've replaced a Honda manifold which cracked in exactly the same place @mikes. I doubt this is an isolated incident and getting an aftermarket part is spot on (besides, Honda charges OUTRAGEOUS prices for parts).